# Submit arrays from form fields to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

There is a sewing management app am working on and on the order page, someone can have multiple orders, but all orders are to be invoiced using one reference code. First page, I collected basic details such as pricing, but on next page, each individual order has to be entered in more detail, a sample picture of the material, instructions and style code if any.

So I've been able to successfully create the page where the data entry person can add multiple details and even select whether there's a style or not, but am stuck in the database submission.

Remember, every other pages am working with, like staff management and others are working just fine, so this error of not submitting to the database is not relative to an external page included or any other thing except probably how the arrays are handled. Below is a breakdown of the code;

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function showfield(name,event){

if(name=='iHaveStyle') {
$(event).next('#div1').html('<label>Enter Style Code</label><br /> <input type="text" name="style[]" />');
} else{
 $(event).next('#div1').html('');
}

}
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".form-group"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
  e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top:20px; border-top:1px solid #333333;"><label>Upload Sample Material</label><br /><input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/><label>Customer&#39s Requirement</label><br /><textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/><label>Do you have a style</label><br /><select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)"><option value="">I don&#39t have a style code</option><option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option></select><div id="div1"></div><br /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
      }
    });
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove  text
  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="orderadd1.php?id=<?php echo "".$order_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<button class="add_field_button">Add another sub-order</button>
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <label>Upload Sample Material</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/>
  <label>Customer's Requirement</label><br />
  <textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /> </textarea><br/><br/>
  <label>Do you have a style</label><br />
  <select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code"  onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)">
    <option value="">I don't have a style code</option>
    <option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-block" value="Continue Order" name="submit_val">
  </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$order_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {

if(is_array($_POST['cust_requirement']))
{
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['cust_requirement']); $i++ ) {

$cust_requirement = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cust_requirement'][$i]);
$style = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['style'][$i]);
$folder = "sample_material/";
$extention = strrchr($_FILES['sample_material']['name'], ".");
$new_name = $order_id."-".$i++;
$sample_material = $new_name.'.jpg';
$uploaddir = $folder . $sample_material;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['submit_material']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir);

$data_submit = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `order_desc` (order_id, sample_photo_url, cust_requirements, style_code) VALUES ('".$order_id."', '".$uploaddir."', '".$cust_req."', '".$style."')");

}}
}

?>
```

The error it is showing is:

> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\header.php on line 2

I checked the header.php and this is exactly what I have there:

```
<?php
 $_POST = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);
 ?>
```

I used this header on all my pages and they are fine.

Comment: Why is this a array? `cust_requirement[]`

Comment: `$_POST['cust_requirement']` is array not string...exactly what error is telling you. Same with others like `$_POST[sample_material]`

Comment: @charlietfl, is there a way you can work around it for me?

Comment: You probably have SQL injection and XSS vulnerabilities in this code. It would be a good idea to submit your application to a security analysis company before going live, or tell your customer to do so. Use bound parameters in your database at all times (`mysql_real_escape_string` is then unnecessary) and make sure you render strings in the view by escaping special characters (`htmlspecialchars`).

Comment: I've fixed it and it now works perfectly. Thanks for down voting the question and calling it off-topic, that's about the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

array_map function applies strip_tags() to every element of an array - but the most possible reason of this is that your $POST looks like this ['test1',['test2','test3]], $POST[1] == ['test2','test3] is an array and strip tags cannot be applied. You can do it using loop and checking if item is not an array to be stripped, or use recursion to go all over you $POST array

Comment: Please, can you guide me on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your POST superglobal contains arrays that is why you get a warning with array_map. Try replacing it with `array_walk_recursive` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Thanks, but am still not very good in PHP, how do i go about it?

Comment: Can you post the output of echo '<pre>'; print_r ($_POST);echo '</pre>';

Comment: This is the output: Array
(
    [cust_requirement] => 
    [sketch_code] => iHaveStyle
    [style] => 
    [submit_val] => Continue Order
)